# How to get discount value round up in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I need to show round value of discount coupon, like if i have apply **10% discount** on cart and after apply if **99.90** value is deducted from subtotal then if need to show **99.90 value round off** and then deduct price from subtotal. 
Is this possible to round off only discount price on cart?

Comment: have you solved it ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153098/how-to-round-off-discount-price

Comment: i solved it  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153098/how-to-round-off-discount-price

Answer (score 0):

copy these file from core to local folder from app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Discount.php.  with same folder structure..

find this function

```
 public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = round($address->getDiscountAmount()); /* round up value */

        if ($amount != 0) {
            $description = $address->getDiscountDescription();
            if (strlen($description)) {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount (%s)', $description);
            } else {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount');
            }
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => $title,
                'value' => $amount
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

change

```
 $amount = $address->getDiscountAmount();
```

to

```
$amount = round($address->getDiscountAmount());
```

Comment: This only seems to effect how the discount is displayed. The grand total remains the same, as if it has been calculated using the non-rounded amount.

Comment: it's round up the discount values only

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

Edit or copy to local folder

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

```
public function roundPrice($price)
    {
        return round($price, 0);
    }
```

Change return round($price, 2);  to return round($price, 0);

This resolved my issue