# How to Round off Discount price?

Tags: magento-1.8, discount, rounding

I copy these file from core to local folder from **app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Discount.php**.

**WHAT I NEED TO DO IS ROUND OFF DISCOUNT VALUE WHICH ALSO ROUND OFF TOTAL VALUE AS WELL **

[image]

I used round function  :

```
 public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = round($address->getDiscountAmount()); /* round up value */

        if ($amount != 0) {
            $description = $address->getDiscountDescription();
            if (strlen($description)) {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount (%s)', $description);
            } else {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount');
            }
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => $title,
                'value' => $amount
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = round($address->getDiscountAmount()); /* round up value */

        if ($amount != 0) {
            $description = $address->getDiscountDescription();
            if (strlen($description)) {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount (%s)', $description);
            } else {
                $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount');
            }
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => $title,
                'value' => $amount
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I solved by above code..

Answer (score 1):

Magento pass discount value as negative value in calculating function,

> E.g
>
> Subtotal = Rs. 100
>
> Shipping = Rs. 20
>
> Discount = Rs. 20
>
> Then,
> Grand Total = Rs. 100

Here,

Magento calculate the discount amount (-20) so, Function just add all the values with (+) sign.

Like , 100 + 20 + (-20) = 100

Comment: how could i correct grand total with round off value

Comment: You can do like this ,        $this->_addAmount(-round($item->getDiscountAmount()));

Comment: not working  it's show total 0.0 and no label show

Comment: Please add your code so can figure out the problem.

Comment: I solved it by same code mention above put some code overwrite it so find out , Normally this code work fine..

Comment: your code didn't work for me.. :P